# Move external application to the front of the screen

Tags: c#, winapi

The application that I'm running needs to call a separate app to do some scanning. I'm calling the other application by starting a new `System.Diagnostics.Process`. Once I get that process, I call a method to give that application the focus. I've tried two different ways to give that external app the focus, but neither are working. Could someone help?

Here's the code:

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    private static extern bool ShowWindow(IntPtr hWnd, uint windowStyle);

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    private static extern bool SetWindowPos(IntPtr hWnd, 
      IntPtr hWndInsertAfter, int x, int y, int cx, int cy, uint uFlags);

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    private static extern bool SetForegroundWindow(IntPtr hWnd);

    private static void GiveSpecifiedAppTheFocus(int processID)
    {
        try
        {
            Process p = Process.GetProcessById(processID);

            ShowWindow(p.MainWindowHandle, 1);
            SetWindowPos(p.MainWindowHandle, new IntPtr(-1), 0, 0, 0, 0, 3);

            //SetForegroundWindow(p.MainWindowHandle);
        }
        catch
        {
            throw;
        }
    }
```

First scenario uses the `ShowWindow` and `SetWindowPos` methods, the other method uses the `SetForegroundWindow` method. Neither will work...

Am I using the wrong methods, or do I have an error in the code that I'm using? Thanks all!

Comment: SetForegroundWindow should work, did you start that app before calling GiveSpecifiedAppTheFocus ?

Comment: Yes, here's the flow. 1) Receive message to send to scan utility, 2) Check if scan utility is running (if yes, go to 4), 3) Start scan utility, 4) Send scan utility the document to be scanned, 5) Give scan utility the focus. I receive no error messages or anything...

Comment: Just tried the ShowWindow/SetWindowPos method again and it works now, but it's ALWAYS on top, even if I click on an app that's in the background. I'm trying the foreground version again...

Comment: SetForegroundWindow does NOT work...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use SetWindowPos, but whenever you don't want the window to be the topmost anymore call it again with the second parameter set to -2 (HWND_NOTOPMOST) instead of -1(HWND_TOPMOST)

Comment: Fantastic, this works!
            private static void GiveSpecifiedAppTheFocus(int processID)
        {
            try
            {
                Process p = Process.GetProcessById(processID);

                //ShowWindow(p.MainWindowHandle, 1);
                SetWindowPos(p.MainWindowHandle, new IntPtr(0), 0, 0, 0, 0, 3);

                //SetForegroundWindow(p.MainWindowHandle);
            }
            catch
            {
                throw;
            }
        }

Answer (score 0):

Try setting your process to the background ie: this.SendToBack();  This is just another solution, partial fix.